# What is the maximum amount of elements that we can store in Byte array in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm working on a watermarking so I am converting PNG image to byte array and then hard-code the values of that byte array in my code.

But when I'm doing this with the image of 100x100 its gives an error that code is too large and as far as I know this error is due to the supported size of an byte array elements which is actually 64kb only.

Please and tell me if there is any better way of doing this thing?

Comment: But one pixel != one byte. PNG images have 4 values (R, G, B, Alpha) per pixel. This is however still less than 64k.

Comment: Where are you talkong about? byte[] bytes = new byte[length]; With length an int. Also bytes.length returns an int. So you can put megabytes in a byte array.

Comment: `code is too large`? You mean 'array is too large'?

Comment: Most likely an error in the conversion code.

Comment: you can put 2GB of data in an array

Comment: I am initializing array in code like this 
byte[] imageInByteBytes = new byte[] {-119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 0, 124, 0, 0, 0, 100, 8, --- upto 18000 elements} as I have told you I am doing it for some watermarking purpose and this is the only solution I have even for the image of size 50x50 has array elements of 86k .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of elements in an array is Integer.MAX_VALUE or about 2 billion regardless of the type of the array.

When you initialise an array in Java, it does so in code, one element at a time.  The assumption is you won't be initialising large arrays in Java.  The limit for any method including the static initialisation block for initialising a Class or a constructor is 64K, and it is this limit which you appear to be hitting.

There is two ways around this;

- read the data from a file.  Then you can have arrays up to 2 GB - 1.
- store the data in a String which is not initialised this way.  You can convert the data to a byte[] using `s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`

Most likely the best option is to store the data in a file.